# tilde delimited file

Tags: csv, dataformat

I need to read a tilde delimited file.

Fields are separated by tilde (~).

But sometimes there are multiple "tilde's" one after another (~~~~~~).

What is the purpose of multiple tildes?

Comment: Perhaps post a larger sample of the file.  That'd help us provide more educated insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its tilde `~` delimited file then two tildes (`~~`) mean the field inside is empty 
This is by definition.

If thats not the case its not tilde delimited

Answer (score 1):

That most likely just indicates the absence of data in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Double tilde implies the column is empty.

Your bbc data has got 14 column from A-N.Put it in spreadsheet and split into columns by selecting tilde as delimiter and you can see the pattern.